# Eclipse Galileo Proxy detection by URL

Tags: eclipse, proxy, galileo

In earlier versions of Eclipse I was able to add an URL to auto detect the proxy settings. How can I tell Eclipse to use an Auto Proxy 
Configuration URL?

THX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you refer to the "old" (3.3) setting:

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/images/proxy.png))</sub>

The new setting also allows for:

- PAC (Proxy Auto Configuration), mode "Native" (default [since 3.4](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=240856), even though that still have some bug like [Bug 257443](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=257443))
- Manual proxy settings, mode "Manual"

[image]
<sub>(source: [eclipse.org](http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.5-200906111540/images/proxy-settings-ui.png))</sub>

See also [How do I set a proxy for the Browser to use?](http://www.eclipse.org/swt/faq.php#browserproxy)